# How to quantify over all subsets in MiniZinc

Tags: minizinc

I would like to create a constraint for every subset of a set of integers in MiniZinc, along the lines of this...

```
constraint forall (S subset C, k in M) (
    % Some constraint over the set S, and integer k
);
```

I'd also like to use the cardinality of `S` in the constraint, and `C` is just a set of integers. Is there a syntax for subset that I can use? (the above model doesn't work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there are no generators for arrays/sets of sets; thus there is no viable way of iterating over all subsets of a given set, other than manually listing the power set in a datafile.

In most cases the model can be re-formulated so that these generators are not necessary. Consider, for example, using a variable set instead:

```
var set of C: S;
% or if you want to declare S in a different way:
% var set of 0..100: S; % Different declaration
% constraint S subset C;
forall (k in M) {
  % some cool constraints
}
```

This would enable you to make models including constraints stating "There is such a set *S*, such that all constraints hold."

Comment: But how would you force the universal quantification over S? It's a forall (S subset C), and not an exists. Can I push a double negation around things somehow?

Comment: @haz To my knowledge there is no direct solution that would fit the situation you would describe. As I said before, the model will need reformulation. If you could provide any details, maybe I could help you further.

Comment: Nah, fair enough. I can re-model things to make it work, but I was just trying to stay faithful to a MIP model listed in a text book to demonstrate the direct encoding in MiniZinc. It will require a different set of vars / constraints, but shouldn't be a big deal. Thanks.